# How to run preinstalled Windows 7 through Ubuntu logged in system?

Tags: windows-7

i have a pc with dual boot - "windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10". is it possible to run my windows 7 through Ubuntu login? if possible what app should i have and please give my instructions to install and use it. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I am not a windows user, I guess you can do something similar with some kind of virtualization technology. I guess some desktop virtualization software like VirtualBox (or vmware, etc) can be used. However you may have got problems that you want to run the preinstalled windows OS ... I am not sure if it's possible with VirtualBox or similar software, as far as I remember I've read somewhere that it's possible in theory though you will have problems: "inside" the virtual machine, win7 will see different hardware "environment' than it would, if it runs on the "bare iron". Some kind of multiple hardware profiles (in windows, I mean) may help. I've just found this, maybe it's useful:

http://www.squidoo.com/use-existing-windows-installation-and-apps-in-ubuntu

Comment: Ok, it's about XP,no idea if the same theory works with win7 ... Maybe it worths a try anyway ...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that for Windows 7. Windows Activation is much stricter than it was for Windows XP. An OEM (vendor installed) version of Windows 7 will almost certainly refuse to run as a VM as it's different "hardware", and it would probably involve a call to Microsoft to get it working again when booting normally.

Comment: Ok, I trust you, as I've told, I am not a windows user at all. Anyway it's not possible to use "hardware profiles" in win7? Interesting ...

Comment: I've run W7 Enterprise version from a native partition in VMWare Workstation under Debian. I had to use Enterprise because my company uses a network licensing server to activate the OSes. I've read about the strict hardware change problems with other versions of W7 though. I'm not sure about the legalities, but you might be able to find an activation "patch" for W7 which would overcome the problem if you only have a Home edition license for example.